# I'm at the boot: prompt

Tags: boot-failure

I have Ubuntu 10.04 on a bootable flash drive. It appears that the configuration file is not there anymore.  I need to know what the commands are to get me back into the system. I am sitting at the boot: prompt now I do know that vmlinuz works but then it says "kernel panic"
and freezes the computer

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the system on the flash drive.

Might possibly work if any files were incorrectly copied.